# Get fps using SDL2 / SFML c++

Tags: c++, sfml, clock, frame-rate

Im looking for a way to reliably get the fps for a game (and for the time being set it as the game's title, unless there is a better way to do it, my TTF is broken -_-). So far I have tried:

```
using an sfml clock
SDL timers
Built in c++ time ( calculate the seconds past midnight, then count how many milliseconds passed since update)
```

This code gives me a single number ( 3 or 2 ):

```
sf::Clock clock;
        float lastTime = 0;
        float currentTime = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        int fps2 = 1 / (currentTime - lastTime);

        std::string lastTimeString = std::to_string(lastTime);
        const char* lastTimeChar = (lastTimeString).c_str();

        SDL_SetWindowTitle(gWindow, lastTimeChar);
```

I just need a better way of going about this.

Comment: I would suggest using c++11's [timing facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) for this. The advantage is you can use either lib for your window/inputs and the timing code need not change (as opposed to using sf::Clock).

Comment: The code you pasted is incomplete.

Comment: `std::string lastTimeString = std::to_string(lastTime);` this is always zero given your snippet...